# function using .reduce() returning array and undefined value

Tags: javascript, function

I wrote out this function that is supposed to take in an array of book objects that are formatted like this:

```
{
    id: "5f447132c30e8abe6c988a8b",
    title: "veniam voluptate magna ipsum officia",
    genre: "Historical Fiction",
    authorId: 37,
    borrows: [
      {
        id: "5f446f2ea6b68cf6f85f6e28",
        returned: true,
      },
      {
        id: "5f446f2ead0070f44676f2f6",
        returned: true,
      },
    ],
  }
```

and return an array that looks like this:

```
[
  { name: 'Science', count: 3 },
  { name: 'Classics', count: 2 },
  { name: 'Historical Fiction', count: 1 },
  { name: 'Travel', count: 1 },
  { name: 'Young Adult', count: 1 }
]
```

so i went and made this:

```
function findMostCommonGenres(books) {
  const mostCommonGenres = books.reduce((genres, book) => {
    const genreObj = genres.find(currGenre => currGenre.name === book.genre);
    !genreObj ? genres.push({
      name: book.genre,
      count: 1,
    }) : genreObj.count++;
    return genres;
  }, []);
  mostCommonGenres.sort((genA, genB) => genB.count - genA.count);
  mostCommonGenres.splice(5);
  console.log(mostCommonGenres);
}
```

but for some reason it is returning the array AND an undefined value like this:

```
[
  { name: 'Science', count: 3 },
  { name: 'Classics', count: 2 },
  { name: 'Historical Fiction', count: 1 },
  { name: 'Travel', count: 1 },
  { name: 'Young Adult', count: 1 }
]
undefined
```

the array it returns is exactly what i need but im not sure where the undefined is coming from or how to get rid of it... any help would be appreciated thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not returning a value in your function `findMostCommonGenres`

If there is no return value then the function by default returns `undefined` and depending on where (Chrome devtools as an example) you run this piece of code you will see the return value printed (in this case `undefined`)

This is how I would write it to not see the `undefined`

```js
function findMostCommonGenres(books) {
  const mostCommonGenres = books.reduce((genres, book) => {
    const genreObj = genres.find(currGenre => currGenre.name === book.genre);
    !genreObj ? genres.push({
      name: book.genre,
      count: 1,
    }) : genreObj.count++;
    return genres;
  }, []);
  mostCommonGenres.sort((genA, genB) => genB.count - genA.count);
  mostCommonGenres.splice(5);
  return mostCommonGenres;
}
console.log(findMostCommonGenres({<your books objects here>}))
```